# Python: Pandas groupby is taking too long time to process large data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, `df` as follows:

```
BLART   Amount Paid   CA_NUMBER   PAYMENT_DATE  Payment Mode     Year_Month
  PC    1040          100000001   10-10-2017      Cheque          2017-10
  PA    220           100000001   12-10-2017      Digital         2017-10
  PB    1460          100000007   04-10-2017      Cash            2017-10
  PB    300           100000007   06-10-2017      Cash            2017-10
  PB    1740          100000001   03-11-2017      Cash            2017-11
  PA    203           100000001   08-11-2017      Digital         2017-11
  PB    1130          100000001   15-11-2017      Cash            2017-11
  PC    6660          100000007   10-11-2017      Cash            2017-11
  PC    6630          100000007   14-11-2017      Cash            2017-11
```

The original data is of `(43802240,11)` size. 
I want to apply a `groupby` method in a way so that for each `CA_NUMBER`, 'Payment Mode' and `Year_Month`, I have last payment amount as well as total invoice amount. So the resultant `df` should like as follows:

```
BLART   Amount Paid CA_NUMBER   PAYMENT_DATE    Payment Mode      Total Invoice    Year_Month
 PC        1040     100000001   10-10-2017       Cheque           1260              2017-10
 PA        220      100000001   12-10-2017       Digital          1260              2017-10
 PB        300      100000007   06-10-2017       Cash             1760              2017-10
 PB        1130     100000001   15-11-2017       Cash             3073              2017-11
 PA        203      100000001   08-11-2017       Digital          3073              2017-11
 PC        6630     100000007   14-11-2017       Cash             13,290            2017-11
```

So as you can see from the above `df`, that for each '`CA_NUMBER`, `Payment Mode` and `Year_Month` we are getting only one row with all the values. Additionally the sum of total invoice for that year month as well.

**My Approach:**

I am using the following `pandas` operation.

```
df_grp = df.loc[df.groupby(['CA_NUMBER','Payment Mode','Year_Month'])['PAYMENT_DATE'].idxmax()]
```

When I do so, the process become awefully slow and eventually I had to restart the kernel again and again. So my question is:

1. Is there any faster way of achieving the same?
2. How can I add the `Total Invoice` column in the above code? Will below code snippets work?

   `df_grp['Total_Invoice'] = df.groupby(['CA_NUMBER','Year_Month']).sum()`

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: May be something like this? `df.groupby(['CA_NUMBER','Payment Mode','Year_Month']).agg(PAYMENT_DATE=('PAYMENT_DATE', 'last'), 
                                           Total_Invoice=('Amount_Paid', 'sum'),
                                           Last_Payment=('Amount_Paid', 'last')).reset_index()`

Comment: Ok lemme check. Why do we need `Last_Payment=('Amount_Paid', 'last')` part? Will it not be automatically populate?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Here we are saying, create a column named `Last_Payment` & contents of the column should be the 'last' value in column `Amount_Paid`

Comment: Ok, using  your method, I am losing out `CA_NUMBER`, `BLART`, `Year_month` etc. How to retain them as shown in the desired output?

Comment: The columns used for group-by(`CA_NUMBER`,`Year_month`) should already be there in the result. If you want `BLART` as well, you need to add it to the `agg` function, something like `BLART=('BLART', 'last')`